# I just tried to do multiple filtering using the below code. but am able to get the row number only at the first and after that am unable

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, autofilter

```
Sub SplitWords()
    Dim TextStrng As String
    Dim Result() As String

    Sheets("CO REPORT").Select
    TextStrng = Range("K6").Value
    Result() = Split(TextStrng)

    For i = LBound(Result()) To UBound(Result())
        Sheets("RSVP SCOPE").Select
        'ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$791").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & 
        Result(i) & "*", Operator:=xlOr
        MsgBox Result(i)
        Worksheets("RSVP SCOPE").Range("1:1").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Set Report = Excel.ActiveSheet

        Dim visRng As Range
        Set visRng = Report.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        Dim r As Range
        Dim j As Integer

        For Each r In visRng.Rows 
            j = r.row 
            MsgBox (j)
            Worksheets("RSVP SCOPE").Range("1:1").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$791").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

For the above code, the split words is being used since there will be multiple words in a single cell. I need to copy a text from sheet1 and search that value in column 1 of sheet2 . Now after filtering I need to display the row number for every selected words. In the above code, the first iteration gets executed successfully. But for the second iteration I get a

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broken. I see trouble:

```
...
       ' Dim r As Range
       Dim r As Variant
...
```